# Query in java does not work

Tags: java, postgresql

I try to run a query from java, i run the query in the postgresql editor and this work, but when running the application does not work, to run the query returns no data

this is the code:

```
private synchronized Perfil consultarPerfil(String nombre) {
    Perfil perfil = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERFIL WHERE NOMBRE = ?";
    Connection connection = conexion.getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, nombre);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            perfil = new Perfil(rs.getString("nombre"), rs.getString("descripcion"), rs.getBoolean("estado"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ColeccionPerfiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        conexion.close(connection);
    }
    return perfil;
}
```

Comment: Are you connected to the correct database?

Comment: Unrelated, but why is the method `synchronized`?

Answer (score 0):

add this : after = 
 like this

String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERFIL WHERE NOMBRE =: ?";

Note: the parameter must have a same data type as the field "nombre" has

Answer (score 0):

If column NOMBRE in table PERFIL is a NUMBER, then when you try to set your parameter as Int like this:

```
 statement.setInt(1, nombre);
```

Instead of

```
statement.setString(1, nombre);
```

Regards,

Comment: Nombre is Spanish for "Name" not "Number". https://translate.google.com/#es/en/nombre

Comment: Thanks for information, but this does not answer to initial question

Answer (score 0):

I try adding : after = but show exception, NOMBRE is string type and I have a database only. The connection works correctly.

I could run the query sometimes from java, but then stopped working and the debugger does not display errors. Restart the computer and clean the cache does not work netbeans.

I are spending a lot of mistakes of this kind lately with java.